# Vector Font on iOS

Tags: ios, fonts

I want to include a vector font file instead of a .ttf file to my application (not Bitmap based).

Unfortunately, I do only see hints regarding an import of .ttf files. The common approach does not work for .svg.

1. Add Font file to build target
2. Add Key to Info.plist file: `Fonts provided by application`
3. Add each Font file to the array

Has anyone made experience with embedding a such in an iOS application or is aware, whether this feature even exists / is being about to be implemented?

Comment: As for iOS I think you can only use vector format for images ( see http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/ , they use pdf). Please, update the post if you find something else.

Comment: @joan thank you. The approach of using PDFs for vector graphics as image is a great approach. But unfortunately, this isn't suitable for vector fonts.

Comment: SVG fonts are not supported even in most browsers, I don't think they are supported by Xcode. Exporting to standard font files is the best option.